# Mondrian 4: Creating Measure Groups according to Virtual Cubes

Tags: olap, mondrian

I am familiar with **Mondrian 3** where I use **Virtual Cubes** when I need to combine measures from two or more *regular cubes*.

I have two cubes `Sales` and `Warehouse`:

- They have three shared dimensions `Product`, `Time` and `Store`.
- And each cube has one own dimension (`Customer` resp. `Warehouse Info`).
- There is one calculated member `Profit Per Unit Shipped` which combines measures from both cubes.
- Note that `ignoreUnrelatedDimensions="true"` is defined for `Sales` cube, so measures from `Sales` cube will have non joining dimension members pushed to the top level member.

Mondrian 3 schema:

```
<VirtualCube name="Warehouse and Sales">
    <CubeUsages>
        <CubeUsage cubeName="Sales" ignoreUnrelatedDimensions="true"/>
        <CubeUsage cubeName="Warehouse"/>
    </CubeUsages>

    <VirtualCubeDimension cubeName="Sales" name="Customer"/>
    <VirtualCubeDimension cubeName="Warehouse" name="Warehouse Info"/>
    <!-- shared dimensions -->
    <VirtualCubeDimension name="Product"/>
    <VirtualCubeDimension name="Store"/>
    <VirtualCubeDimension name="Time"/>

    <VirtualCubeMeasure cubeName="Sales" name="[Measures].[Sales]"/>
    <VirtualCubeMeasure cubeName="Sales" name="[Measures].[Unit Sales]"/>
    <VirtualCubeMeasure cubeName="Sales" name="[Measures].[Profit]"/>
    <VirtualCubeMeasure cubeName="Warehouse" name="[Measures].[Units Ordered]"/>
    <VirtualCubeMeasure cubeName="Warehouse" name="[Measures].[Units Shipped]"/>

    <CalculatedMember name="Profit Per Unit Shipped" dimension="Measures">
        <Formula>[Measures].[Profit] / [Measures].[Units Shipped]</Formula>
    </CalculatedMember>
</VirtualCube>
```

I know I need to use **Measure Groups** instead of Virtual Cubes within **Mondrian 4** schema definition. How can I create Mondrian 4 schema with Measure Groups which corresponds to Mondrian 3 schema above?